# Amazon S3 SOAP in URL returns empty 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have a static site hosted on Amazon S3 with a CloudFront CDN. There is a 404 error page in CloudFront that redirects to the site to be handled on the client side (react routing).

All 404 pages work correctly but if I have "/soap" in the URL, it returns a 200 and a blank response. I believe s3 is returning a 200 instead of a 404 when /soap is in the URL.

How would I prevent s3 from intercepting /soap requests and return a 404?

Comment: What does `/soap` return locally? Are you *sure*         your React app doesn't have a route for it?

Comment: S3 doesn't have a `/soap` route configured - can you also add a screenshot of how you've set up static website hosting?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it's not set for website hosting, we are serving it through cloudfront and adding a policy to only allow cloudfront to access the bucket.

Comment: if I run the react site locally I get a 404 but when it's hosted on s3 then I get a 200 empty response.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot please for that as well as the above requested? super strange!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have an Improper directory control. Instead of directly copying build outputs in s3 bucket, first create a folder with random name and paste the build output in that random folder.
Now you have to provide Origin path in your Cloud Front distributions. For setting origin path, you need to open your Cloud Front distribution console and select Origins tab and then  select your Origin then click on edit, you can now find Origin path section under settings. Now you have to provide your random folder name there with '/'. (For example: `/Random Folder`). Now you can check this with "/soap" in the URL it will redirect to your Error Page.

For setting Origin Path you can refer the following link:
[Setting Origin Path in AWS Cloud Front Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html?icmpid=docs_cf_help_panel#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath)